# Google Maps Embed API not showing traffic when using waypoints

Tags: google-maps-embed

I am building a web page where I can select a source and destination location and then show the distance, travel time (with current traffic) and actual traffic on a Google Map.

The Google Maps API documentation suggests to use the Google Maps Embed API, as so (route = Paris to Amsterdam):

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?origin=Paris&destination=Amsterdam&key=APIKEY"></iframe>
```

This works fine.
Now I want to add waypoints to the routes so that I am certain specific route will be selected and shown, as so (route = Paris to Amsterdam via Brussels):

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?origin=Paris&destination=Amsterdam&waypoints=Brussels&key=APIKEY"></iframe>
```

In this case no traffic is shown and the calculated travel time doesn't include the delays because of traffic. You can also see the effect on [this page](http://users.telenet.be/cinarius/Routes/GoogleMapsEmbedAPITrafficTest.html) I built to show the issue.

I didn't find in the Google Maps Embed API documentation that traffic is not shown when using waypoints. Is this a bug or didn't I read it well enough? Are there alternatives to the Google Maps Embed API?